# setValue points to the object instead of copying the NSString

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsstring, nsmutablestring, setvalue

I'm parsing an XML document. I have an `NSMutableString` to hold the value for each node I'm passing through and for specific nodes - I want to update the `NewsElement` class.

This is my code:

```
[newsElement setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
```

The currentElementValue is the `NSMutableString` the the elementName is key I want to update. Each field is `NSString`.
The problem is that instead of copying the string, now my `NSString` points to the currentElementValue address so all of the fields are always the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably copying `currentElementValue` would fix your problem.  Have you tried:

```
[newsElement setValue:[currentElementValue copy] forKey:elementName];
```

This will make an immutable copy (i.e. an `NSString`) of the `currentElementValue` which is an `NSMutableString`.  If you need the copy to be mutable you could use the `mutableCopy` method instead, for example:

```
[newsElement setValue:[currentElementValue mutableCopy] forKey:elementName];
```

Comment: yup - that did the trick... Any memory hit because I copy the whole element instead of just its string value?

Comment: I have no idea, you haven't given enough context to know what is happening.  What is `currentElementValue`, from your question I had assumed it was an `NSMutableString`?

Comment: In that case I'm not sure what you mean by "copy the whole element instead of just its string value".  The `copy` method will make a copy of the value of the `NSMutableString` at that moment in time.